# Vector Derivatives Demonstation

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

i would like to demonstrate this derivative

$ J =  - \left(p + \frac{1}{2} v^2 \right) \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}$

$ \dfrac{\partial J}{\partial \boldsymbol{v}} = - \left(p + \frac{1}{2} v^2 \right) \boldsymbol{n} - \left( \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \right) \boldsymbol{v}   $

Thanks for help

Comment: If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy using components. You have
$$
J=-\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3v_i^2\right)\sum_{j=1}^3v_jn_j.
$$
Then,
$$
\frac{\partial J}{\partial v_k}=-\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^3v_i^2\right)n_k-v_k(\sum_{j=1}^3v_jn_j).
$$
Getting back from components to vectors, you are done.

Answer (score 0):

In this special case, you can also consider $J$ as it was a function of a "single variable" $\boldsymbol{v}$:

$$J=f(\boldsymbol{v})\cdot g(\boldsymbol{v})$$ with

$$f(\boldsymbol{v})=- p - \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v} $$

and

$$g(\boldsymbol{v})= \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n}$$

and apply product rule:

$$J'=f'(\boldsymbol{v})\cdot g(\boldsymbol{v})+f(\boldsymbol{v})\cdot g'(\boldsymbol{v}) = \\=-\boldsymbol{v}(\boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n})+\left(- p - \frac{1}{2} \boldsymbol{v}\cdot\boldsymbol{v}\right)\cdot \boldsymbol{n}=\\= - \left(p + \frac{1}{2} v^2 \right) \boldsymbol{n} - \left( \boldsymbol{v} \cdot \boldsymbol{n} \right) \boldsymbol{v}$$

**NOTE** In generale it's recomended to proceed by components as Jon did.